# ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener implementation

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using spring-kafka in production for the first time so it might be a naive question. I am using `@KafkaListener` to consume my messages. In the `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` I have added an implementation of `ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener`. My use case is pretty simple I want to commit the offsets of the records that have been processed but because of repartition that happened beacuse of session timeout I could not commit them. Now the issue is that `onPartitionsRevokedBeforeCommit` is getting called even on `onPartitionsLost` and so I get the exception since the consumer does not have the partitions anymore. Now I can live with it as in I can log the exception and raise an alarm and reprocess the messages. but  was thinking if there is a better way to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `onPartitionsLost` in the listener and set a boolean to ignore the call to `onPartitionsRevoked` this time around (and reset the boolean).

If the boolean is false, it means it's a normal `onPartitionsRevoked`).

Comment: thanks @Gary Russel that will work. One unrelated question if we have to stop or start consuming messages can I use `code KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.stop()/start()` method for that

Comment: Don't ask unrelated questions in comments; it doesn't help people find questions/answers. That will stop/start all registered listeners; to control the lifecycle of individual listeners, use `registry.getListenerContainer(id).stop()`.